# swift loop for...in core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I need to loop into a core data to compare two values, I try to do it with a for...in.

I'm using `fetchedResultController` to create my request on my Core Data:

```
func getFetchedResultsControllerUser() -> NSFetchedResultsController{
    frcu = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequestUser(), managedObjectContext: context!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frcu
}

func taskFetchRequestUser() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}
```

and on my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I declare my user object: `let user = frcu.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! User`

This is the user class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(User)
class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var task: NSSet

}
```

Once I'm there, I try to loop on user to get a specified id:

```
for userId in user.id{
      if (userId == task.responsable){
            responsible = user.name
        }      
}
```

task is `let task = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Task`, I can add code about this if needed.

but it doesn't work, I have the error `Could not find an overload for "==" that accepts the supplied arguments` line `if (userId == task.responsable)`

Am I on the good way, what am I doing bad?

I just try to compare task.responsable with every user.id and if I get a matching value, I print the corresponding user.name.. It's a very common thing with a traditional ORM, but there I'm stuck...

**ps: My final aim is:**

***Compare the `task.responsable` string with every `user.id` and if I get a matching value, print the corresponding `user.name` of the `user.id`***

This is the Task Entity and it's frc:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Task)
class Task: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var context: String
    @NSManaged var date: String
    @NSManaged var detail: String
    @NSManaged var folder: String
    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var responsable: String
    @NSManaged var status: String
    @NSManaged var summary: String
    @NSManaged var user: User
}

var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

func getFetchedResultsController(String) -> NSFetchedResultsController{
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(folder), managedObjectContext: context!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}

func taskFetchRequest(String) -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Task")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "folder = %@", folder)
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "summary", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}
```

Comment: Please can you show how the `Task` entity is defined.  What type is the `responsable` attribute?

Comment: Code just edited, Responsable is a String, just like the user.id, we don't have to cast one of them

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem lies in your for-in loop.  `user` (lower case u) is a single `User` object - so the `for-in` loop is not iterating through all the `User` objects.  Because `user.id` is a `String`, the loop is iterating through each character of that string in turn.

To iterate through all of the User objects, use the fetched results controller's `fetchedObjects`.

```
for user in frcu.fetchedObjects! as! [User] {
    if (user.id == task.responsable){
        responsible = user.name
    }      
}
```

Comment: I'll try this in a few minutes, thanks a lot for your answer, It's probably what I was looking for, the explanations are clear for me, thanks. I'll accept the answer as soon as i'll having tried it.

Comment: So it works, thank you very much, I was searching for days without succeed to understand what was wrong, if I need to run through an Entity, I have to use the fetchedObjects which is an array on any Object and cast it as an array of my class (user in this case). I remember this and will read a bit more about the `fetchedObjects`, once again thank you pbasdf

Comment: Look also at the `executeFetchRequest:` method of [NSManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/executeFetchRequest:error:).  That will return an array of NSManagedObjects (or your subclass) without the need to use a fetched results controller.

Answer (score 0):

Swift logic is a little different in comparatives , instead of using `==` , try to use `if let` state like the code below

```
if let userId = task.responsable {
    // here userId is defined as responsable
}
else{
   // userId is not task responsable
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct, the OP is trying to compare a `userId` against `task.responsable`, but your answer is unwrapping `task.responsable` and assigning it to the value `userId`.

Comment: I just try to find a way to compare a `task.responsable` with every `user.id` and if I get a match result, printing the corresponding `user.name` of the `user.id` matched.